# CakePHP HABTM relationship table joins

Tags: cakephp

I have a 'patient_cases' table with a HABTM relationship with a 'procedures' table. This 'procedures' tables has a many to one relationship with 'consultants' table, which then has a many to one relationship with 'specialties' table.

The relationships are working fine and using cakephp debug tool bar i can see everything is coming through correctly when i look at 'patient_cases' index page, however i'm only getting consultant_id and specialty_id rather than all of the fields with that associated model.

which is what should be happening i believe -

> In CakePHP some associations (belongsTo and hasOne) performs automatic
>   joins to retrieve data, so you can issue queries to retrieve models
>   based on data in the related one.
>
> But this is not the case with hasMany and hasAndBelongsToMany
>   associations.

I want to be able to get the consultant name from 'consultants' table using procedures.consultant_id and get the specialty name from 'specialties' using consultant.specialty_id.

I have tried playing about with some table joins but with no success,

```
class PatientCase extends AppModel {    
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
                'Procedure'             => array(
                'className'              => 'Procedure',
                'joinTable'              => 'patient_cases_procedures',
                'foreignKey'             => 'patient_case_id',
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'procedure_id',
                'unique'                 => true
            )
    );
}

class Procedure extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
            'Consultant'        => array(
                'className'     => 'Consultant'
            )
        );

}

class Consultant extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
            'Specialty' => array(
                'className'     => 'Specialty',
                'conditions'    => array('Specialty.active' => 1)
            )
        );
    public $hasMany = array(
            'Procedure'
        );
}
class Specialty extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array(
            'Consultant'
        );
    );
}

$this->set('patientCases', $this->PatientCase->find('all'));
```

Returns everything i need, each model array is returned (other relationships not mentioned here), however the model array 'Consultant' is not returned, which also means i can not get the 'Specialty' data which is linked to the 'Consultant' model

**EDIT**
I have managed to get the data i need by using this in my PatientCasesController

```
$this->set('patientCases', $this->PatientCase->find('all'));
$this->set('patientCaseProcedures', $this->PatientCase->Procedure->find('all'));
```

However, ideally i want to return everything in the one 'patientCases', is this possible?

**EDIT**
I have solved the problem using the recursive function

```
$this->PatientCase->recursive = 3; 
$this->set('patientCases', $this->PatientCase->find('all'));
```

Comment: You should be getting all the data by default. Please add some code to your question to see how you are retrieving it.

Comment: Off-topic, but you might also try to use the Containable Behavior, which adds much finer control over 'what information' should be included in your result, especially when using complex relations. As a bonus, it sometimes generates more optimised queries as well (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)

Comment: For very specialised queries, it's always possible to hand-code queries and execute them via MyModel->query(); e.g. When executing stored procedures, you'll need to take care of escaping values yourself then (binding is possible though)